# Kendo grid - пользовательская навигация по таблице

Tags: javascript, kendo

Как сделать навигацию в Kendo Grid стрелками, чтоб при нажатии кнопок вверх и низ изменялась выделенная строка, по нажатию кнопки "Вправо" раскрывалась группировка, а по нажатию кнопки "Влево" группировка схлопывалась?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Навигацию кнопками Вверх Вниз можно сделать следующим образом

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        { field: "name" },
        { field: "age" }
    ],
    dataSource: [
        { name: "Olivia Duke", age: 30 },
        { name: "Amelia Beckham", age: 34 },
        { name: "Sam Claflin", age: 29 },
        { name: "Laura Haddock", age: 30 },
        { name: "Benedict Cumberbatch", age: 28 },
        { name: "Sophie Hunter", age: 37 },
        { name: "Tom Hardy", age: 25 },
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
    ],
    navigatable: true,
    selectable: 'row',
    });
    var data = $("#grid").data('kendoGrid');
    var arrows = [/*37, */38, /*39,*/ 40];
    data.table.on("keydown", function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    if (arrows.indexOf(e.keyCode) >= 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            data.select($("#grid_active_cell").closest("tr"));
        },1);
    }})
});
```

Проверить работоспособность кода можно по [ссылке](http://jsfiddle.net/xms1bjnr/2/)